# C Compiled Executable Not Running

Tags: c

I wanted to run an Hello World program as I am starting in C :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
        printf("Hello World\n");
        return 0;
}
```

I compile it with this command :         **gcc h4.c -o h4**

It create the executable h4 and when I click on it the command prompt pop and get shut down directly its like its running but to quick for me to see before it shut down.

Comment: If you simply compile from the Command Prompt (or PowerShell), simply type `h4` and run it from the terminal itself. That way the automatic terminal window created when you double-click on `h4` doesn't close before you have a chance to read the output. Compiling and running from the Command Prompt itself is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the command `./h4` in your command prompt to run the program but keep the prompt open.
Clicking on the executable also does "runs" the program, but it closes the window after the execution is finished.

Seems like you are on Windows. In this case, you don't need the prefix `./`,just simply `h4.exe`. Or, if you really want to, you can use `.\`.

Comment: I tried that too and it is always the same :                                                                               
 ./h4
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Mister-3 Seems like you're on windows, see the edited solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not running it on your command prompt
do this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Hello world\n");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Assuming your on windows, you should just type `h4` instead if you want to run it on your command prompt.

Comment: What u mean by not running inside my cmd ? like A compiler with a GUI?

Comment: Just do 'h4' not './h4'

Comment: Oh no, not `getch()` and not `conio.h` that is 100% NON-portable to anything other than DOS/windows. Instead simply use `getchar()` provided by `stdio.h` and wrap it in a conditional that is only triggered on DOS/windows, e.g. `#if defined (_WIN32) || defined (_WIN64) getchar(); #endif` (each on its own line)

Comment: Yes I agree with you. He is using windows so that's why I came up with conio.h. Although getchar() is more suitable.